# Is activated sludge process efficient for industrial waste water treatment ? why if isn't?

Tags: waste-water-treatment

The main raw water has following parameters, water comes from a soap manufacturing factory

- pH 7.1
- BOD 520 mg/L
- COD 4890 mg/L
- TSS 360 mg/L
- No Oil & Grease

if you need expected treated effluent data
 - pH 6.5-8.5
 - BOD <50 mg/L
 - COD <30 mg/L
 - TSS <250 mg/L
 - Oil & Grease <10 mg/L

Is activated sludge process efficient for industrial waste water treatment of this kind of raw water? what are the reasons if it isn't a good way to treat such raw water. Any recommendations with reputable sources such as research papers etc?

my proposed process is initial sieve filtration --> airation --> addition of floc (bacteria and protozoa) --> settling tank --> gravity filtration

I'm really new to this and trying to understand it.

please letme know if I asked it in a incorrect way. thanks

Comment: I finf it odd that in the expected effluent data, max. COD is smaller than max. BOD. What's the unit for Oil & Grease?

Comment: it's just the accepted levels. Shouldn't it be smaller than BOD?. The unit is mg/L ..

Comment: 1) BOD is usually a part of COD, so that BOD is higher in the same water makes physically no sense. Doesn't mean the limits are not what they are. 2) I think with the high COD and high COD/BOD ratio in the raw wastewater that an AS process won't achieve much. But I can't back this hunch up easily so I can't provide a real answer.

Answer (score 1):

The BOD/COD ratio of this wastewater is low enough that it would be impractical and most likely toxic to the microbiology of an activated sludge process. [Here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.261.2969&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is a good review of the general characterization of wastewater based on BOD, COD, and BOD/COD ratio.